# python pydeck to_html not rendering map

Tags: python, pydeck

I am using heatmap layer from pydeck. It works find when I do `map.show()` however when I save it to html file using `map.to_html("name.html")` it shows heatmap without mapbox on the background.

Here is my code:

```
layer = pdk.Layer(
    "HeatmapLayer",
    df,
    get_position="[st_lng, st_lat]"
) 
center = [126.962351, 37.398356] 
view_state = pdk.ViewState( 
    longitude=center[0], 
    latitude=center[1],
    zoom=10
)
map = pdk.Deck(layers=[layer],
             initial_view_state=view_state,
             mapbox_key=MAPBOX_API_KEY,
             map_style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
)

map.to_html("a.html")
# r.show()
```

outputs: `'C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\name\\a.html'`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was using Pydeck version 0.2, updating it to version 0.5.0 solved my problem.